# Generalization of strong and closed profunctors

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory, profunctor

I was looking at the classes of strong and closed profunctors:

```hs
class Profunctor p where
    dimap :: (a' -> a) -> (b -> b') -> p a b -> p a' b'
class Profunctor p => Strong p where
    strong :: p a b -> p (c, a) (c, b)
class Profunctor p => Closed p where
    closed :: p a b -> p (c -> a) (c -> b)
```

(`(,)` is a symmetric bifunctor, so it's equivalent to the definition in "profunctors" package.)

I note both `(->) a` and `(,) a` are endofunctors. It seems `Strong` and `Closed` have a similar form:

```hs
class (Functor f, Profunctor p) => C f p where
    c :: p a b -> p (f a) (f b)
```

Indeed, if we look at the laws, some also have a similar form:

```hs
strong . strong ≡ dimap unassoc assoc . strong
closed . closed ≡ dimap uncurry curry . closed

lmap (first f) . strong ≡ rmap (first f) . strong
lmap (. f)     . closed ≡ rmap (. f)     . closed
```

Are these both special cases of some general case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add `Choice` to the list. Both `Strong` and `Choice` (or cartesian and cocartesian, as Jeremy Gibbons calls them) are examples of Tambara modules. I talk about the general pattern that includes `Closed` in my blog post on [profunctor optics](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/07/07/profunctor-optics-the-categorical-view/) (skip to the Discussion section), under the name `Related`.

Comment: I was thinking to note `Choice` in my question but the docs of the "profunctors" package already say it's another notion of strength so i left it out. Anyhow, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Very intriguing. This isn't really an answer, just thoughts...

So what we need is an abstraction over `(,)` and `(->)` which offers generalisation of `assoc`/`curry` and `first`/`precompose`. I'll address the former:

```
class Isotropic f where
  lefty :: f a (f b c) -> f (a,b) c
  righty :: f (a,b) c -> f a (f b c)
  -- lefty ≡ righty⁻¹

instance Isotropic (,) where
  lefty (a,(b,c)) = ((a,b),c)
  righty ((a,b),c) = (a,(b,c))

instance Isotropic (->) where
  lefty = uncurry
  righty = curry
```

Easy. Question is, are there any other instances of this? There's certainly the trivial one

```
newtype Biconst c a b = Biconst c

instance Isotropic (Biconst c) where
  lefty (Biconst c) = Biconst c
  righty (Biconst c) = Biconst c
```

Then the resulting profunctor

```
class Profunctor p => Stubborn p where
  stubborn :: p a b -> p (Biconst d c a) (Biconst d c b)
```

could as well be written

```
class Profunctor p => Stubborn p where
  stubborn :: p a b -> p d d
```

But the instances of this seem to come out rather too trivial as well, to be any use:

```
instance Stubborn (->) where
  stubborn _ = id
instance (Monad m) => Stubborn (Kleisli m) where
  stubborn (Kleisli _) = Kleisli pure
instance (Monoid m) => Stubborn (Forget m) where
  stubborn (Forget _) = Forget $ const mempty
```

I suspect that `(,)` and `(->)` really are the only useful cases for this, because they are the “free bifunctor” / “free profunctor”, respectively.